# PowerApps - Display user from People Picker in a text field as First Name Last Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, powerapps-forms, display-name, format

I have what should be a simple task, but I'm struggling with it.  It's a large form, so I'll just stick to what's relevant for my question.  So I have a people picker field in my form (customized SharePoint form), and a Text field.  When the user populates that People field with whomever they're choosing, I want the Text field to display that user's First and Last Name only.  Currently my company's people fields present like this when populated - Shoemaker, Chris (Companyname).  I want my Text field to just display, Chris Shoemaker.  In that order without the "(companyname)".  Here are my fields:

PeoplePicker - Datacardvalue5
Text - Datacardvalue6

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Technically this formula meets your requirements:

```
Trim(
    $"{Last(
        Split(
            First(
                Split(
                    DataCardValue5.Selected.DisplayName,
                    "("
                )
            ).Value,
            ","
        )
    ).Value} {First(
        Split(
            First(
                Split(
                    DataCardValue5.Selected.DisplayName,
                    "("
                )
            ).Value,
            ","
        )
    ).Value}"
)
```

However, I would suggest that it is prone to failure. If there are edge cases where a user has a bracket or comma in their name, it would absolutely break.

My recommendation would be to add the Office365Users or AzureAD connector to your app, and use a formula something like this for your text field:

```
With(
    {tmpUser: Office365Users.UserProfileV2(Last(Split(DataCardValue5.Selected.Claims,"|")).Value)},
    $"{tmpUser.givenName} {tmpUser.surname}"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately the People picker field won't ever technically have a Selected value, because that field has a DefaultSelectedItems formula that automatically displays a name based on another People field.  So the first formula you listed.  When I enter that formula, the Text field remains blank unless I manually select a user from that People field.  The second formula gives me an error that I haven't seen before: The function UserProfileV2 has an invalid value for parameter "id".

Comment: I might be making this harder than it has to be.  Basically I have a Project dropdown for the user to select.  I then have a People field that displays the Project Director associated with that selected project - {Value: ComboBox2.Selected.DisplayName} (in defaultselecteditems).  This data won't write to Sharepoint when I submit for some reason.  So I added two text fields, one for the Project Director's name, and the other for Email.  Problem is when I use - ComboBox2.Selected.DisplayName for the new text field, it displays it as Shoemaker, Chris (companyname)